# Терминал Wsl и Power shell не выполняют команду node.js

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Пытаюсь освоить Node.js и как-то не выходит. Пакет установил под виндоус, в Path указал путь, через npm поставил в Wsl терминал, но тем не менее когда пытаюсь запустить файл командой node index.js, выдаёт ошибку. Сижу туплю.[image: module_not_found]

Comment: Там же в ошибке написано, что по указанному пути нет указанного файла(модуля) для запуска

Comment: Написано, жаль не уточняется где ещё этот путь нужно прописывать. Т.к сам node определяется, через отладку файл запускается, а терминал вот не хочет

Comment: У вас в вашей директории **..., сайты** есть файл index.js?

Comment: да, в сайтах ещё одна папка, в ней index, нужно команду иначе написать?

Comment: вот и надо писать **node folder\index.js**

Comment: убрал из названия папки пробелы, запустил таким путём- сработало. Благодарю  за ответ, забываю про такие вещи порой.